# PuTTY session window lauched from Windows taskbar shortcut doesn't get focus

Tags: windows, putty

Using PuTTY 0.74 on Windows 10 20H2, launching saved sessions by selecting from the taskbar PuTTY icon's context menu opens a window without focus, i.e. I have to click in the session window to bring it to the front before I can type into it. Launching the saved session from within PuTTY opens the window with focus, as does launching the session from the Windows CLI. I've tried clearing the PuTTY sessions in the registry, un- & re-installing multiple times including the development snapshot... Is this normal behavior, and is there a fix?

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I had this issue using Stream Deck to open putty. I solved it by updating Stream Deck. Was not a putty bug imo.